# Getting Source Annotation in KCachegrind

Tags: c++, macos, x11, valgrind, kcachegrind

I'm trying to view source code associated with the executable `lab13`. When I click the **Source** tab in KCachegrind, all I see is the following:

```
There is no source available for the following function:
    'main'
This is because no debug information is present.
Recompile source and redo profile run.
The function is located in this ELF object:
    'lab13'
```

However, I am using the `-g` debugging flag in my `makefile`:

```
lab13:main.o
    g++ -g main.o -o lab13
    ./lab13

main.o:main.cpp EdgeArray.h Edge.h DisjointSets.h Matrix.h experiment.h
    g++ -c -g main.cpp
```

I created the `callgrind.out` file using the following call to `valgrind`:

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind --dsymutil=yes ./lab13
```

I looked at the [KCachgrind documentation](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/GUIViews.html), but there is no information on how to activate the **Source** tab feature.

I compiled the program on OSX and am running KCachgrind via X11. I am reading the `callgrind.out` file from the same directory as the code. All other KCachgrind features appear to work.

How do I get the **Source** tab working?

Comment: Can you go through the program line by line with `gdb`?

Answer (score 0):

You should look for the "fl=" lines in the profile ([cf](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-format.html)) and make sure the source files are available under the paths given in the "fl=" lines.